# Custom keras metric error

Tags: machine-learning, keras, machine-learning-model

I'm trying to create a new metric for my model and this is my function

```py
def my_acc(y_true, y_pred):

    if(y_pred > y_true):
      x = ((y_pred-y_true)/y_true)*100
    else:
      x = ((y_true-y_pred)/y_true)*100

    a = 100 - x   
    return(a)
```

When I'm trying to use the above function in the model the following error occurs

```py
def train_model():

  optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(0.001)
  model = build_model()
  model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
                loss= 'mean_squared_error',
                metrics=['mean_absolute_error', 'mean_squared_error','accuracy',my_acc])

  logdir = os.path.join("logs", datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S"))
  tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(logdir, histogram_freq=1)

  model.fit(train_dataset, train_labels,
            validation_split = 0.2, 
            epochs=500,  
            callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])

train_model()
```

`````py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-847c0f5f49e0> in <module>()
     15             callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])
     16 
---> 17 train_model()

12 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in __bool__(self)
    688       `TypeError`.
    689     """
--> 690     raise TypeError("Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. "
    691                     "Use `if t is not None:` instead of `if t:` to test if a "
    692                     "tensor is defined, and use TensorFlow ops such as "

TypeError: Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. Use `if t is not None:` instead of `if t:` to test if a tensor is defined, and use TensorFlow ops such as tf.cond to execute subgraphs conditioned on the value of a tensor.
````
`````

Comment: metrics must be differentiable

Comment: can you explain about that, please

Comment: If you do not only calculate a metric as callback for your own information, Keras will try to optimize over this metric. This is what you did, if I understood the code correctly (?). For gradient decent, the function must be differentiable. https://ml-cheatsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gradient_descent.html

Comment: Thanks. I am new to ML. I think I have more to cover

Comment: I kind of solved the problem. it was the " >" symbol that was causing the issue. I  thing Keras wasn't able to understand  " > ".  I changed that line of code in to
```python
x = abs((y_pred - y_true)/y_true)*100
```
but now there is a new problem my_acc is always showing inf